# getDistanceMatrix service in google map returns status "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT" for some set of coordinates

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-distancematrix-api

I'm using a single origin. When I check with sample latitude longitude values in the example given in the google maps documentation it's working. But If I change the coordinates it's not working returning "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT".

The Below code is working fine

```
origin1 = new google.maps.LatLng(55.930385, -3.118425);
    this.service.getDistanceMatrix(
      {
        origins: [this.origin1, this.origin2],
        destinations: [this.destinationA, this.destinationB],
        travelMode: 'DRIVING',
        transitOptions: TransitOptions,
        drivingOptions: DrivingOptions,
        unitSystem: UnitSystem,
        avoidHighways: Boolean,
        avoidTolls: Boolean,
      }, (response, status) =>{
        console.log('duration='+response.rows[1].elements[1].duration.text);
      });
```

But when I change that origin1 latlng values. then it returns OVER_QUERY_LIMIT

Comment: please read the pricing and policies (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix#UsageLimits)
"If too many requests are made within a certain time period, the API returns an OVER_QUERY_LIMIT response code."

Comment: but when I'm using LatLng(55.930385, -3.118425) its working fine. Issue is occurring when I change the coordinates.

Comment: are you using the same API Key for both requests?

Comment: Yes same Api key. I'm just changing the coordinates.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: Hi I've edited my question. Please check now.

Comment: Ok One thing I found out is this. On a day only one request I can send using getDistanceMatrix.

Comment: That was an issue with my google account. Mine is a billing account and my trial period is not over yet. But you should have a full account to send more requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comment that you shared above, you are able to call the API for the first time and the succeeding requests doesn't work anymore, this error is usually caused by billing not enabled or associated to the project, please note that an active billing account is now required to further use the Google Maps APIs.

Upon setting up your billing account, you will be entitled to have one time $300 free credit (Usable for any Google Cloud Platform products) and a monthly recurring $200 free credit (Exclusive for Google Maps API only), so you can still use these APIs without being billed.

And in case you already exhausted the one time $300 credit and your monthly recurring $200 credit, you will not be billed for extra charges but you will get a degraded experience upon reaching your quota, if you wish to not encounter degraded experience upon consuming your free credits, you may upgrade your billing account and you will be billed accordingly.

You may visit this [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/billing/understanding-cost-of-use) to learn about the pricing of each APIs.

If you wish to limit your usage in order to control the consumption of your credits, you may visit this [link](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/capping-api-usage) to learn about capping API usage.

Should you need further assistance to this, please file a support case via https://console.cloud.google.com/google/maps-apis/support in order to open personalized communication channel.